# extjs 5 Error while setting value to the combobox with remote values

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs5

Having form panel with combo box in it

```
Ext.define('MyApp.admin.view.UserAddView', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.admin.controller.UserAddViewController'
    ],
    controller: 'userAdd',
    autoScroll: true,
    frame:true,
    items: [{
        xtype:'combobox',
        fieldLabel: 'Roles',
        collapseOnSelect: true,
        editable: false,
        multiSelect: true,
        queryMode: 'remote',
        queryParam: undefined,
        displayField: 'authority',
        bind: {
            store: '{role}'
        },
        name: 'authorities'
    }]
});
```

Then I want to set values dynamically to this combobox from the view controller

```
var ob = {'authorities': 'ROLE_ADMIN_USERS'};
var panelToAddName = Ext.create('MyApp.admin.view.UserAddView', {});
panelToAddName.getForm().setValues(ob);
```

Every time I receive an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

in the following line

```
panelToAddName.getForm().setValues(ob);
```

There is no such a problem if the store is specified locally inside combobox

```
store: ['ROLE_ADMIN_USERS']
```

I guessed there is a problem related to remote list is not loaded when setValue is called, but setting queryMode: 'local', and loading store with list from view controller doesn't fix the issue.

Is there a way to set value to the combobox with remotly loaded list from view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured the issue out by setting

```
queryMode: 'local'
```

then loading store from the view controller

```
var storeRole = me.getViewModel().getStore('role');
storeRole.load();
```

then bindStore of the combo box

```
var combobox = panelToAddName.items.getAt(0).items.getAt(0).items.getAt(0).items.getAt(2);
combobox.bindStore(storeRole);
```

If somebody knows how to get combo box in more simplistic way you are welcome to comment. The following does not have a bindStore() method

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox')[0]
```

Comment: `panelToAddName.down('combobox[name=authorities]');`

Comment: configure a reference name on the combo and then in the controller you can use this.getView().lookupReference('yourReferenceName'). Of course it should be unique per view ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with **bind** config of your **combobox**. In Ext5 doc, there is not config with name **bind** for **combobox**.

If your store name is **role**, try writing `store:'role'` instead of **bind**.

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately setting store:'role' results in error "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined" when I try to create the view. BTW as you can see here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/whats_new/5.0.1/whats_new.html "Developers may now use “selection” as a bindable property on certain components. These components include ComboBox..." so since extjs 5.0.1 it is possible to bind store in combo box